# How can we pass X509 Certificate upon calling FHIR API?

Tags: hl7-fhir, intersystems-iris

We need to pass X509 Certificate while calling FHIR API. How can we achieve the desired ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: X509 validation is normally handled at the TLS connection layer, which is something that is established before you even make a FHIR call.  Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?